# How can I take a value from a line edit to another window's line edit by using Python and PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

**What I need:**

I need to create a simple project that can take value from window to another window

**My research effort:**

So, I create two classes for two windows then connect to classes with each other, so when I click in button it takes the value from 1st window then open the other window but the value=nothing because the `clickMethod` returns nothing.

**Below is my code:**

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(320, 140))    
        self.setWindowTitle("First Window")

        self.nameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel.setText('1st:')
        self.line = QLineEdit(self)

        self.line.move(80, 20)
        self.line.resize(200, 32)
        self.nameLabel.move(20, 20)

        pybutton = QPushButton('OK', self)

        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.second_wind)  #connect button to open second window
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        pybutton.resize(200,32)
        pybutton.move(80, 60)        

    def clickMethod(self):
        value =self.line.text() #take value from the line edit
        return value

    def second_wind(self):    #object from secod_window class
        self.SW = Second_Window()
        self.SW.show()




class Second_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(320, 140))
        self.setWindowTitle("Second Window")
        self.nameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel.setText('Name:')
        self.line = QLineEdit(self)

        self.line.move(80, 20)
        self.line.resize(200, 32)
        self.nameLabel.move(20, 20)
        self.f = MainWindow()        #make object from MainWindow class to execute clickMethod() to reutrn value
        a=self.f.clickMethod()
        print(a)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

I expect the Clickmethod to  return the value
but it returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(320, 140))    
        self.setWindowTitle("First Window")

        self.nameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel.setText('1st:')
        self.line = QLineEdit(self)

        self.line.move(80, 20)
        self.line.resize(200, 32)
        self.nameLabel.move(20, 20)

        pybutton = QPushButton('OK', self)

        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.second_wind)  
#        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        pybutton.resize(200,32)
        pybutton.move(80, 60)        

#    def clickMethod(self):
#        value =self.line.text() 
#        return value

    def second_wind(self):    
        text = self.line.text()                                    # +++
        self.SW = Second_Window(text)                              # +++ (text)
        self.SW.show()


class Second_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, text):                                      # +++ (text)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.text = text                                           # +

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(320, 140))
        self.setWindowTitle("Second Window")
        self.nameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel.setText('Name:')
        self.line = QLineEdit(self)

        self.line.move(80, 20)
        self.line.resize(200, 32)
        self.nameLabel.move(20, 20)

#        self.f = MainWindow()        
#        a=self.f.clickMethod()
        self.line.setText(self.text)                                # +
        print(self.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

[image]